# Add column to df1 from df2 by condition

Tags: dataframe

I have got 2 pandas DataFrames called df1 and df2.

Df1 contains 29000 rows and 1 column with not unique "PSP" strings (Ex.: "XG-100000-12345") called "PSP". Df2 contains 500 rows of unique strings and 2 columns of information. One that is called "PSP" and one called "Funk". For every unique "PSP" in df2, there is an associated unique "Funk"(Ex.: "34563-123").

Now I want to iterrate over every single row of the df1 column "PSP" and compare it to the the df2 column "PSP" and if the df1 column "PSP" are equal to the df2 column "PSP", I want to insert the associated "Funk" into a new column called "Funk" on the same row as the "PSP" matched in df1.

I know its badly explained, but let me try to illustrate it:

```
df1:              df2:                               df1 (after the iterration):  
column "PSP"      column "PSP"    column "Funk"      column "PSP"   column "Funk"
XG-12000-123      XG-12000-653    45345-123          XG-12000-123   54675-126       
XG-12000-345      XG-12000-123    54675-126          XG-12000-345   35686-345                      
XG-12000-653      XG-12000-345    35686-345          XG-12000-653   45345-123                        
XG-12000-567      XG-12000-567    45678-387          XG-12000-567   45678-387                        
XG-12000-345                                         XG-12000-345   35686-345
XG-12000-567                                         XG-12000-567   45678-387
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
df1["Funk"] = df1.PSP.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[x].Funk)
```

This means, you are creating a new column "Funk" with the contents that are created after applying the lambda function, which takes the Funk-value from df2 from the line with index x, ie. the value in df1, onto column PSP in df1.

Edit: you mentioned, that you don't have an index. So you might try it like this:

```
def _lookup(table, x):
    row = table[table.PSP == x]
    if len(row) == 0:
        return None
    return row.iloc[0].Funk

df1["Funk"] = df1.PSP.apply(lambda x: _lookup(df2, x))
```

Comment: if I run this, I get: ValueError: no axis named .... for object type <class 'type'>.

Comment: Can you give me the whole exception there? By omitting the name I cannot tell you, where my snippet potentially broke.

Btw: is PSP in df2 an index-column? My solution somehow assumes this as otherwise I cannot use x in this lambda as the key.

Comment: ValueError: no axis named XG-1350800002-23000 for object type <class 'type'>. It's definitely because the PSP-column in df2 is not an index-column. I could change it to be the index-column, but could you maybe come up with a solution without this change is necessary?

Comment: Please check my answer again. I added an Edit-section. Maybe this will help you. Please let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Now I get "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds". I didn't change the index of df2. So I still have df1 with an index-column and  column "PSP" (29000 rows) and df2 with an index-column, "PSP" column and "Funk" column (900 rows).

Comment: Could you please show me what you get if you execute this here: `df2[df2.PSP == 'XG-12000-123]`?

Comment: I get:  702      PSP: XG-12000-123     Funk: 54675-126

Comment: I made another edit. It seems to me like you have values in your PSP column in df1, that have no corresponding entries in the df2 table

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.